# Circular Path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, circular-dependency

I am stuck at developing a circular path algorithm creating a path out of points.
This is the array I am starting with:

```
(1,1)
(1,6)
(2,2)
(2,5)
(4,1)
(4,2)
(6,5)
(6,6)
```

These are points in a coordinate system and I want to be ordered so I only need horizontal or vertical lines between the adjacent points. So the sorted array needs to look like this

```
(1,1)        (A,H)
(1,6)        (A,B)
(6,6)        (C,B)
(6,5)        (C,D)
(2,5)        (E,D)
(2,2)        (E,F)
(4,2)        (G,F)
(4,1)        (G,H)
```

EDIT: These points are extracted out of the different edges. Every edge is defined by two points. There are no edges which overlay each other.

```
Edge: (1,1) -> (1,6)
Edge: (1,6) -> (6,6)
Edge: (6,6) -> (6,5)
Edge: (6,5) -> (2,5)
Edge: (2,5) -> (2,2)
Edge: (2,2) -> (4,2)
Edge: (4,2) -> (4,1)
Edge: (4,1) -> (1,1)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This is not sorting, just some kind of ordering. If it were sorting, you could take any 2 points and tell which is "bigger", and which is "smaller". Here, order of next items depends on order of previous.

Comment: As I understand, here you try to build a circular path connecting N points, each edge of which must be horizontal or vertical, and every horizontal edge must be followed with vertical and vice versa. If you have only 0 or 2 points for any given x or y coordinate (as in your example), there is only one such path (not taking into account direction of traversal), if it exists, and can be recovered quite simply. If for any given x or y there can be any even number of points, problem becomes harder.

Comment: You are right. Ordering is the correct definition for my problem. I am able to go one step back, where I do have the different edges defined by two points, I figured it would be easier to work with points instead, but I forgot about the possibility of two edges using the same point

Comment: May edges intersect?

Comment: Yes, they can intersect

Comment: The starting array you provided has only 1 solution (or 2 if you count reverse) Is this always the case?

Comment: @RaGe yes there is only one path (and the reversed version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing, than edges must alternate (every vertical to be followed by horizontal and vice versa), algorithm may be the following:

```
P = input // collection of points
EH = []   // collection of horizontal edges
EV = []   // collection of vertical edges

sort P by x, then y         // (1,1), (1,2), (1,4), (1,6), (2,2), (2,5), ...
for (i = 0; i < P.size; i += 2) 
    if P[i].x != P[i+1].x return   // no solution
    EH.add(new edge(P[i], P[i+1]))

sort P by y, then x         // (1,1), (4,1), (2,2), (4,2), ...
for (i = 0; i < P.size; i += 2)
    if P[i].y != P[i+1].y return   // no solution
    EV.add(new edge(P[i], P[i+1]))

// After this, every point belongs to 1 horizontal egde and 1 vertical
// If exists closed path which traverses all points without overlapping, 
// such path is formed by these edges

S = []          // path
S.add(EH[0])
cp = EH[0].p2   // closing point 
p =  EH[0].p1   // current ending point
find edge e in EV where e.p1 = p or e.p2 = p
if e not found return empty path      // no solution
S.add(e)   
if p = e.p1
    p = e.p2
else
    p = e.p1
while (p != cp) {
    find edge e in EH where e.p1 = p or e.p2 = p
    if not found return empty path    // no solution
    S.add(e)
    if p = e.p1           
       p = e.p2
    else
       p = e.p1
    find edge e in EV where e.p1 = p or e.p2 = p
    if not found return empty path    // no solution
    S.add(e)
    if p = e.p1 
       p = e.p2
    else
       p = e.p1
}
return S
```

To simplify edge search, mentioned collections `EV` and `EH` may be implemented using hash maps (point, point), where for each actual edge `e(p1, p2)` two entries should be put: `p1->p2` and `p2->p1`. Every point belongs to 1 horizontal and 1 vertical edge, so entries won't be overwritten. Thus second part of algorithm may be simplified:

```
while (p != cp) {
    get from EH point pp by key p
    if not found return empty path    
    S.add(new edge(p, pp))
    p = pp
    get from EV point pp by key p
    if not found return empty path    
    S.add(new edge(p, pp))
    p = pp
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will implement this and test it and come back to you!

Comment: @PNGamingPower okay. Now I'm trying to find cases to break this algorithm, but still cannot find any.

Comment: @PNGamingPower are horizontal edges and vertical edges always expected to alternate?

Comment: @RaGe very valuable point since algorithm I described will work correctly only when every horizontal edge is followed by vertical and vice versa.

Comment: yes, add (5,5) to the initial set, as a counter-example for your algorithm.

Comment: @RaGe adding (5,5) will require 2 consequent horizontal edges (6,5) -> (5,5) -> (2,5). As I said, supposed that edges must alternate

Comment: @RaGe do you have solution better than O(3^N) for case when edges aren't required to alternate? So far I succeeded only with O(3^N) recursive solution...

Comment: No, I dont. Just to add: the problem as stated is effectively a [find a hamiltonian-cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem. Given that we don't know that a solution exists at all, we're in NP-complete space. There might be a DP solution.

Comment: @RaGe if so, solution has exponential complexity

Comment: @SashaSalauyou for a general case solution, yes, I believe so. There may be conditions specific to this problem that could allow shortcuts. Like the implementation in your answer - which is pretty neat, except we need OP to confirm the assumption is true.

Comment: @RaGe the only additional condition here that I see is that degree of vertices never exceed 4 (that's why brute force will solve it in 3^N, not N!)

Comment: Edges will always alternate. If not, the edges will be combined.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Thank you very much! The algorithm is working perfectly